# Event listener in java

Tags: java, apache-commons, event-listener

We desing our application with base classes and Event Listener approch, thus the base class and a event listener interface. base class invoke appropriate event listener method after call any operation. Following code shows my design :

```
import java.util.EventListener;

public interface MyEventListener extends EventListener
{
    public void preOperation();

    public void postOperation();
}
```

Then I implement this interface as following :

```
class MyEventListenerImpl implements MyEventListener
{
    @Override
    public void postOperation()
    {
        System.out.println("Do previous operation");
    }

    @Override
    public void preOperation()
    {
        System.out.println("Do post operation");
    }
}
```

Then I write base class as following :

```
abstract class Base
{
    private MyEventListener eventListener; /* this member injected */

    public abstract void operation_1();

    public void doOperation_1()
    {
        eventListener.preOperation(); /* call listener before invoking main operation_1 implementation */

        operation_1(); /* call main operation_1 implementation */

        eventListener.postOperation(); /* call listener after invoking main operation_1 implementation */
    }
}
```

after these works I write my implementation of Base class and implement operation_1 method.
I do this approach by **java.util.EventListener** marker interface but after design my problem see another class :

1. Abstract class **EventListenerProxy** in  java.util package.
2. EventListenerSupport generic class in org.apache.commons.lang3.event package.

I don't know using these class never. I want know two things:

1. Your opinions about my design.(good or bad)
2. best practice for **Event Listener** approach.(by said class or any third party frameworks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to discuss about a particular design without knowing which problem it's supposed to solve.

Anyway, the principal problem with your design is that you can only have one listener. Using `EventListenerSupport` would allow easily supporting several ones, and would make the add/remove listener methods trivial to implement.

Another problem is that your listener methods don't take any event as parameter. This makes it impossible for a single listener to listen to several `Base` instances, because it can't use the event to detect the source of the event.

Comment: My Listener is sample and real listener methods have parameters.

Comment: So, you ask us to discuss your design without telling us which problem it's intended to solve, and without showing us your actual design?

Comment: I discuss my design for event listener, not all classes and all interface,because those large and not useful for my question.

Comment: Yes, except you show us a listener interface that doesn't look like your actual one. That's like saying: - Please taste my new desert. - It's disgusting. - Yes, but this is not my new desert. In my real new desert, I use other ingredients, and I put more sugar in it. What's the point?

Comment: I say generalities of all design, and if you discerned I must discuss complete my code,I will do.

Comment: So, your question boils down to "Is it a good idea to use event listeners?". My answer is: yes, sometimes, but sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

An EventListener, by nature, can not know that something *will* happen, because it is triggered from inside `operation_1` in your example.

What you are looking for are AOP method interceptors. Especially aopalliances MethodInterceptor interface will be useful to you:

```
public Operation1Interceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {

    /* feel free to access the arguments, if you wish */
    foo(invocation.getArguments())

    Object retval = invocation.proceed();

    /* Log it or do whatever you want */
    bar(retval);

    baz();

    return retval;
  }

}
```

The easiest way to use that is Google Guice, but there are some tutorials around.